# Will OData Service implement both metadata document and service document definitely?

Tags: odata

I'm new to the OData protocol.
I saw that it seems like there are 2 types of well-defined resources that describe the OData Service Data Model, which are Service Document and Metadata Document.

But I want to know that if both of these two resources can be found at the OData Service definitely / for sure?

Since I did not see any restriction from the OData specifications that OData Service must fulfil these 2 resources together during implementation, I guess that there is only one type of Service Data Model that can be found from service.

I really appreciate if any one can help to clarify it.

Thanks!

Comment: Answered in another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934473/every-odata-service-will-provoide-metadata-document

Comment: Answered in another thread [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934473/every-odata-service-will-provoide-metadata-document

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which libraries is used to implement the OData service. For example, if the service is implemented using ASP.NET Web API for OData or RESTier, the two documents will both exist for sure.